# How do you use dask to groupby column and apply with custom function without running out of memory?

Tags: python-3.x, dask, dask-dataframe

I know I can do this easily on spark but have been trying with dask and keep getting out of memory errors, maybe I'm not doing it correctly.

Here is the situation: I have a very large dataframe, let's call it `df`. `df` has 2 columns: key and amount

```
   key  amount 
    1 4.2
    1 4.3
    1 4.2
    2 4.1 
    2 4.1
    2 4.3
```

I have a custom function:

```
def process(df):
    // a lot of processing 
    // cant be written in dask
    return df
```

As you can see process operates on the entire dataframe and returns a new dataframe that has been processed. The stuff inside process cannot be translated into dask.

I need to partition by key (so I get 1 dataframe per key), run process on each key's dataframe and then combine them back into a single data frame and finally write it as csv.

I have tried `df.groupby("key").apply(process).to_csv(...)` but run out of memory.
I have also tried `df.map_partitions(...).compute()` but also run out of memory

I read the docs and even tried `df.map_partitions(lambda x: x.groupby(..).apply(proc))` but realized this does not work as the groups are not isolated by partition.

I know this is an easy thing to do what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Hi John! Welcome to stack overflow. For best results, try to include a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) in your question. This will help us be more precise about the key challenges you're facing, as well as to debug the issue ourselves. One question I have is - does the process function need to have all elements of the group on the first go? Could you run this with multiple passes? e.g. what about `df.map_partitions(lambda x: x.groupby(...).apply(proc)).groupby(...).apply(proc).compute()`?

Comment: Hi @MichaelDelgado thanks for replying yes the process function does need to have all elements of the group on first go unfortunately. I can't share everything but example could be proc just sorts all elements and then adds 1 to amount

Comment: ok - yeah if you can't provide info on your needs that's a tough one for us to help with. I'd check out the docs on [`dask.dataframe.Aggregation`](https://docs.dask.org/en/latest/dataframe-groupby.html#aggregate) and see if you can implement aggregators which handle memory more efficiently. Try to dump as much data as soon as you can during your first aggregate step.

Comment: this helps. can I ask is there a way to set partitions in map_partitions to be the index of my dataframe (or another column)? I think that would solve my problem

Comment: I'd recommend reading the dask.dataframe docs - they're pretty great. Check out [best practices](https://docs.dask.org/en/latest/dataframe-best-practices.html#), [dask.dataframe.groupby](https://docs.dask.org/en/latest/dataframe-groupby.html), [common uses and anti-uses](https://docs.dask.org/en/latest/dataframe.html#common-uses-and-anti-uses) especially. If none of this works for you, you could always use dask bag or delayed.